# How is $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)| = |\lim_{x\to a}f(x)|$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, absolute-value

The title basically says it all. My book states that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)| = |\lim_{x\to a}f(x)|\ 
$$
in proving that, if $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, so is $|f(x)|$.
Why is this true?

Comment: The absolute value function is continuous.

Comment: I agree that the comment of @MarkSaving is conclusive.  Another way of saying the same thing is that if there exists a finite $L$ such that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$, then $|f(x)| \to |L|$ as $x \to a$.

Comment: @MarkSaving  So, in general, $\lim g(f(x)) = g(\lim f(x))$ if $g$ is continuous?

Comment: @AadiPrasad Yes. In fact, $\lim g(f(x)) = g(\lim f(x))$ for all $f$ is equivalent to $g$ being continuous (just take $f(x) = x$ to see it)

Comment: @MarkSaving  Oooh, now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: In effect, what these comments signify is that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, then within the domain where $(g \circ f)$ is defined, so is $(g \circ f).$  That is, the composition of two continuous functions is itself continuous, at least in the realm of either Real Analysis or Complex Analysis.  I can't speak re fields other than $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}.$

Comment: For the equality to make sense, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ must exist, which is the case if $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a direct application of two facts:

1. The absolute value function $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous;
2. The composition of continuous functions is continuous.

The second fact is very standard. The first is a consequence of the reverse triangle inequality $\big||x|-|y|\big|\leq|x-y|$: for $\varepsilon>0$, if $\delta=\varepsilon$, then for $|x-x_0|<\delta$:
$$\big||x|-|x_0|\big|\leq|x-x_0|<\varepsilon,$$
so $|\cdot|$ is continuous at $x_0$ for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

From this, we can conclude that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)|=\left|\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\right|,$$
by the fact that continuity implies sequential continuity; that is, if $x\to x_0$ and $g$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $g(x)\to g(x_0)$. (Here we're applying the fact that $|\cdot|$ is continuous at $f(x_0)$.)